# how not to ignore punctuation marks in postgresql sorting?

Tags: database, postgresql

My SQL query

```
select name
from products
order by "name" asc
```

My result:

```
AAA
BBB
!!!CCC
DDD
```

I noticed that the sign ! is ingorged by postgresql, how to fix it to be considered for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need special sort support for non-ASCII characters (e.g., you don't rely on `ß` being sorted like `ss`), you could use the binary collation (and ignore case):

```
ORDER BY lower(name) COLLATE "C"
```

If you have more advanced requirements, and your PostgreSQL is build with ICU support, you can create a custom ICU collation that puts more emphasis on special characters.